# DB2 queries get occasional SQL0925N: Processing cancelled due to interrupt error

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, db2

I have a .Net application which interacts with a DB2 database (Entity Framework, not sure if that detail is important).  *Occaisionally* I will get the following error on queries:

```
ERROR [57014] [IBM][DB2] SQL0952N  Processing was cancelled due to an interrupt.
```

This is the entire error text (the inner exception).  It does not have a SQLSTATE.

Again, this does not happen every time (even for the same query).  For instance, I can run the same query over and over again and only see the error happen 1 out of 5 times.  The duration of the query is always fairly consistent.

I have searched for some documentation and found the following:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21450816

Just in an attempt to troubleshoot, I followed a suggestion in the above docs and set `QueryTimeout=0` in my connection string.  This did not help, I still get the error at about the same rate.  I even tried `QueryTimeout=500`... same result.  What is interesting is that in testing, when this error occurs it happens at roughly the 30 seconds mark (which the documentation mentions is the default timeout).  Am I still using the default timeout setting somehow?

Connection string below:

```
<add name="myConn" connectionString="(entity framework stuff);provider=IBM.Data.DB2;provider connection string=&quot;Database=myDB;User ID=myId;Server=myServer;QueryTimeout=0&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

1. Could there be some other timeout setting that is overriding or taking precedence over the setting I am specifying in the connection string?
2. Is it possible I am *not* dealing with a timeout issue but some other issue?  I have read that this can be an indication of locking... but I can reproduce this in test being the only person accessing the database at the time. Could it be something else?

**EDIT**

I just tried setting `QueryTimeout=1` thinking that this would for sure cause every query to time out.  This seems to have had no affect.  4 out of 5 queries still completed after taking WELL over a second.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Actually, I think 57014 _may_ be the SQLSTATE.  What platform/version are you using, I'm seeing different text for that SQLCODE.  30 seconds tends to be the default timeout for file locks, yes, but there are a number of ways even just **you** can lock a file (different threads come to mind).  Is it only a simple query?  Are there any triggers that may unexpectedly lock something?

Comment: It is only a simple select.  There are no triggers, and nothing else comes to mind... DB2 version 9.7.5 fix pack 5

Comment: Hmmm... looks like the [official documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00952n.html) indicates the system may think it's received an interrupt message (ie - 'this query is taking too long, forget it').  Is there a maximum time on your application side, that could cause it to send an interrupt on its own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by setting the `CommandTimeout` on my EF data context like this:

```
using (dataContext = new myDB2Entities())
{
     dataContext.CommandTimeout = 60;
     // DB CODE
}
```

I understand now that the `QueryTimeout` setting I had been trying to use is simply a time interval, and at every interval the database checks to see if the application is still waiting for a response.  I had not addressed the fact that the application was issuing an interrupt after the default 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The error is SQL0952N

To solve, I executed the command from DB2 Command line

db2 UPDATE CLI CFG FOR SECTION COMMON USING QUERYTIMEOUTINTERVAL 0

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql0952n-error-returned-long-running-sql-statement